# How to show image (Bitmap) in compose with glide, coil

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-glide, coil

I want to insert a picture into my composable GlideImage or CoilImage or Image. I get a picture depending on the conditions from resources/drawable (image.jpg) or from mobile galery(Uri). For Image(){} I decode my image to bitmap. How to use bitmap for glide and coil?

W

myList:
LazyColumn(
state = listState
) {

```
            itemsIndexed(
                items = listCycle,  // list items from Viewmodel: val listCycle by cycleVM.cycles.collectAsState()
            ) { _, it ->
                CycleItemCard(cycle = it, navHostController)
            }
        }
```

my Item for Lazycolumn:

```
@Composable
fun CycleItemCard(
    @PreviewParameter(SampleCycleProvider::class) cycle: Cycle,
    navHost: NavHostController
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(1.dp)
            .clickable {
                navHost.navigate(NavigationItem.DetailCycleNavigationItem.routeWithId(cycle.id))
            },
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(0.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
        ) {
/////////HERE
        Image( modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .height(50.dp)
            .width(50.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(getImage(cycle, context)),

                contentDescription ="" )
  ////// END          
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = cycle.title!!,
                    style = MyTextTitleLabel16,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )

                if (!cycle.isDefaultType) {
                    Divider(
                        modifier = Modifier

                            .height(1.dp)
                            .padding(end = 8.dp)
                            .background(Color.Black)
                    )
                }

                if (!cycle.isDefaultType) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.End)
                            .padding(end = 8.dp, top = 4.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = cycle.finishStringFormatDate,
                            fontSize = 12.sp,
                            color = Color(0xFF6c6c70)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

my fun for image:

```
fun getImage(cycle: Cycle, context: Context): Bitmap {

    val name = context.packageName
    var source: ImageDecoder.Source
    try {
        if (cycle.image != null) {
            source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, Uri.parse(cycle.image))

        } else {
            val id = context.resources.getIdentifier(cycle.defaultImg, "drawable", name)
            source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.resources, id)

        }
    } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
        val id = context.resources.getIdentifier("drew", "drawable", name)
        source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.resources, id)

    }
    return ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
}
```

No matter what I use(Coil, Glide or Image), LazyColumn lags a lot when scrolling :(

---

```
    I don't know right or wrong. I did this: added to 

CycleItemCard:
          val image = remember {
                mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(
                    Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).apply {
                        eraseColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorBackgroundConstrateLayout))
                    }
                )
            }
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
                coroutineScope {
                    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        image.value = getImage(cycle, context, name)
                    }
                }
            }
     Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .width(50.dp)
                        .clip(CircleShape),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    bitmap = image.value!!.asImageBitmap(), //// here
    
                    contentDescription = ""
                )
```

Comment: what did you try until now?

Comment: I use Image(bitmap = getMyBitmap()...) with a bitmap.

Comment: fun getMyBitmap(): Bitmap { 

Return  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know right or wrong. I did this: added to

```
CycleItemCard:
          val image = remember {
                mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(
                    Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).apply {
                        eraseColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorBackgroundConstrateLayout))
                    }
                )
            }
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
                coroutineScope {
                    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        image.value = getImage(cycle, context, name)
                    }
                }
            }
     Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .width(50.dp)
                        .clip(CircleShape),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    bitmap = image.value!!.asImageBitmap(), //// here
    
                    contentDescription = ""
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    AsyncImage(
        model = ImageRequest
            .Builder(context)
            .data(Uri)
            .crossfade(true)
            .build(),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp, 60.dp)
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_error),
        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_ placeholder)
    )
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: LazyColumn lags a lot when scrolling :(

Answer (score 0):

Using [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) provide various types including bitmaps or images from files, URIs, or URLs. However, if you're dealing with images stored locally, the **Image Composable** suffices, eliminating the need for [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). These libraries are primarily essential when you're working with remote sources, such as loading images from the **internet**.

```
AsyncImage(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data("your bitmap here")
        .crossfade(true)
        .build(),
    contentDescription = null
)
```

Comment: No matter what I use(Coil, Glide or Image), LazyColumn lags a lot when scrolling :(